# Why does English spoken by a native Spanish speaker sounds pleasant but not so pleasant when spoken by a native Indian/Arabic/Chinese?

Tags: etymology, pronunciation

When in fact, both are non-English speakers and are at same level of understanding of English language.   **Could there be any etymological reason behind this?**
**Added later**- *As i can see, people are not so happy with the word 'pleasant'. So let me be more specific, let us assume there is a Spanish and an Asian, both have never spoken English in their lives. A gentleman decided to teach them how to read and after a week, he gave them a paragraph to read. Let us say, I happened to be there when both the speakers were reading it aloud and I found Spanish fellow's diction more pleasant(although both were pleasant).*
**p.s**- This question is not meant to offend anyone. If it does, I apologize in advance. Rather than focusing on unnecessary details, concentrate on the basic question. I know what I described is subjective but this is the case. I don't think I am the only one who has observed this thing.

Comment: I think it's a valid question (it seems as though there are differences in how 'pleasant' people find the accents of non-native speakers in English... and I assume in any language) but your personal experience may not be representative of everybody. For example, I find the accented English spoken by many native Arabic speakers to be quite pleasant.

Comment: Beauty is in the [ear] of the beholder. What sounds "pleasant" is **entirely** subjective.

Comment: That said, I suspect there is something relevant about the sounds in the speaker's native language and how those sounds fit (or don't fit) into English; and vice-versa.

Comment: I think the question should be rephrased to eliminate the purely subjective "pleasantness" of a spoken accent. Also, I fail to see how etymology would affect a listener's perception of an accent?

Comment: @oerkelens question has been edited. Don't concentrate on word 'pleasant'. It's a general observation and i suppose you understood what i meant to ask in my question.

Comment: Unless you can identify how you "measure" pleasant, it will be very hard to find any answer. Personally, I find the Indian accent more pleasant than the Spanish. If your question is why _you_ find the Spanish more pleasant, how can we answer that? It is a matter of taste. If you can give examples of _differences_ in the accents, we might try to find explanations for it :)

Comment: Hey, how about the question reads like this: "IF you agree that .... then why is it .... ?" I'm not sure if people are being PC trolls or what...

Comment: I have no problem with the word pleasant, apart from it being subjective. Honestly, there is no PC motive in trying to point out that subjectivity. But "more pleasant" is as useful as "I feel a Belgian accent is more orange than a German one. How come?"

Comment: @d'alar'cop What's a PC troll?

Comment: PC = Politically Correct. A PC troll would be someone overreacting (on purpose) to a perceived non-politically correct statement, i.e. something that might be perceived as discriminatory.

Comment: @oerkelens thanks ! And yes you sound like a PC troll. In fact, everybody who is highlighting the "pleasant" part. You are missing the core of this question. In other words, everybody is going off on a tangent.

Comment: I resent the assumption that pointing out the unmeasurable subjectivity of "pleasant" is seen as PC. The same problem would exist for "blue". I don't give a rodent's posterior about how pleasant, nice, sexy or funny one finds an accent, I am simply pointing out that these qualities are too subjective to explain their causes without first agreeing on what the observed phenomena are.

Comment: I dare say that _you_ are missing the whole point as to _why_ people are highlighting "pleasant". It means something else to everyone, and a lot of people will have opposite experiences from you. Hence the simple(?) request for specification. I have never been "offended" or "angry" by your use of pleasant - something that "PC"-insinuation _has_ managed, though.

Comment: @oerkelens We all watch TV, we see memes on internet. Don't you know what I am implying? Let me put it this way. A Frenchman and a South Asian went to a Masquerade ball in New York(This was their first trip to USA and both were terrible with English). Since the faces were hidden and they had to persuade a girl to dance with them, they had to impress the girl by talking to her(both guys were not so polished in English). As it happened, the girl chose the Frenchman. This is a real story. I know this is subjective. Could you GUESS why girl chose the Frenchman and not the guy with Indian accent?

Comment: "What are the reasons why English with an Indian accent is more attractive than English with a Spanish accent to some people and less attractive to others?" might be an interesting question, though it is too wide for this site: Linguistics might be interested.  But 'Which accent do you think this person finds more attractive and why?' is off-topic, purely opinion-based, and far too broad. 'Which accent do you find more attractive?' is in addition mildly offensive. And GUESSING is not what we do here.

Comment: Sandeep Dhamija, where you wrote "*let us assume there is a **Spanish***", you should write the word ***Spaniard*** http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/spaniard?q=Spaniard

Comment: @TimLymington We don't guess. But do we observe? The question was based on an observation. The impression I'm getting is "Do not ask a question unless it can be described in literal and quantitative terms". And yes, it is opinion based i admit. But this is the part of question -"Why do majority of people find a particular accent better than the other". It's not my personal opinion. I have OBSERVED it in general life. Hence, arose the curiosity.

Comment: Have you observed the majority of people? You have one story, one observation, and you conclude that _all_ girls will prefer to dance with a guy with a Spanish accent? What choice would you make, and can _you_ explain why you would make that choice? You are now asking us to guess a motivation for an action we might not take. If _I_ happen to like carrot cake, could I ask _you_ to explain to me why "most people in general prefer carrot cake over chocolate"? Can you explain to me why "most people's favourite colour is orange"?

Comment: Maybe rephrasing it to "how do language accents influence people's perceptions of the speakers and their attitudes towards them" would be a very viable question, but I think I agree with @TimLymington's assessment that such a question is too wide and out of scope here, though on Linguistics they might well jump on it :) (And honestly, I would follow it with interest!)

Comment: It would be a legitimate question on Linguistics, and probably Cognitive Sciences. It's the question of the melody of the language and what sounds consonant/dissonant for people speaking a particular langunage. On CogSci you could ask about the mental processes, that make us feeling some language/dialect/accent as pleasure or unpleasure.

Comment: After doing some research I have found a few possible reasons:- a)absence of unvoiced consonants in Hindi/Arabic [eg when Hindi speakers say or speak English words containing t or d, they curl the tongue back and touch the tip to the roof of the mouth and use vocal cord. It produces a very thick sound. Try it] b)Different stress and intonation pattern than English and other European languages(I believe they are derived from same language system)

Comment: This a WTF question to evoke WTF response.

Answer (score 2):

Spanish is simply closer to English - so the sounds are all familiar and many of the words are as well. People find Spanish itself "pleasant-sounding" as well - this is probably, again because of the familiar sounds and the way those sounds are woven together. Chinese, being altogether different, will cause an altogether different sounding English.

So, essentially, it's a matter of habit and familiarities (even mouth shapes).

Comment: I'm currently in an English speaking country - and am a Spanish speaker as well. AND I have close friends from China.

Comment: Also, I have a lady-friend from India... and I'm even down with some Arab folk.

Answer (score 1):

This is an entirely subjective judgement. What sounds pleasant depends on the associations the sounds of speech have for the individual hearing them.

Comment: It could still be the case that *some* or *most* native speakers find the accent of native speakers of X to be more pleasant than that of Y, in which case it's interesting to ask why the distributional variations exist.

Comment: We cannot conclude that without extensive research into the matter. Experiments have shown, however, that reactions to British accents have nothing to do with the quality of the sounds produced and everything to do with the associations they have: West Country = nice holidays, Midlands – dark, satanic mills.

Comment: @BarrieEngland I have added a little story in question description. It's a general observation.

Comment: @BarrieEngland That is interesting, do you have a link to those experiments?

Comment: @ChrisTaylor you seem to understand my question. Even in my country, Hindi spoken by a speaker of a particular area is considered cooler than the Hindi spoken by a speaker of other area. It's a fact. I don't understand why people are so angry about word 'pleasant' ?

Comment: The whole question is covered in the chapter entitled ‘Italian Is Beautiful, German Is Ugly’ in ‘Language Myths’ by Bauer and Trudgill http://tinyurl.com/mb27j5a
Here’s an extract: ‘The pleasantness, or otherwise, of a language variety . . . are contingent on the social attributes of the speakers of it . . . [I]t is the social connotations of the speakers of a language variety . . . that dictates our aesthetic (and other) judgements about the language variety’.

Answer (score 0):

Whether a way of speaking English is "pleasant" is very subjective and different from person to person who listens to the speaker. As to me, I think it would be more important whether I can understand the speaker or whether I have difficulty in understanding the speaker. Non-experienced speakers often speak a foreign language such as English with all the features of their mother-tongue and that influences, of course, whether you can understand him, more or less. 
Etymology is the field of philology that tries to find the origin of words and studies the history of words in the course of centuries and their semantic development. So etymology has nothing to do with the way someone speaks English.

Comment: Ok right. Let me tell you a story and then i'll ask a question. The story is about John Bill who lived in NY. One day as John was returning from work, he was approached by god. God told him that he would lose his natural accent and he has only two options, either choose Spanish accent or Indian accent and whichever he chooses, would stay with him for rest of his life. John replied but i couldn't hear it. As a regular guy, what do you think was his answer? Could you guess his answer and complete the story? I won't judge you. It's off the record.

Comment: If I were John, I'd say "Indian". My guess is that if you were John, you'd say "Spanish". But John is John, so only God knows :)